# How to define function that takes a Class that implements interface in flow?

Tags: javascript, flowtype

Example:

```
interface IClass {
  test(arg: String): Promise<*>
}

class MyClass implements IClass {
  async test(arg) { await dosomething(arg) }
}

async function useIt(TheClass: IClass) {
  const obj = new TheClass()
  obj.test('arg')
}
```

However, this results in:

```
const obj = new TheClass()
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^ constructor call. Constructor cannot be called on
const obj = new TheClass()
                ^^^^^^^^ IClass
```

Which, I understand, as IClass is the interface, but how would one go about specifying a "class" that implements a specific "interface" as a parameter to a function?

Comment: How are you calling `useIt`? It looks like you want the parameter to be a constructor function that returns an `IClass`, but you've typed it as an instance of `IClass`.

Comment: Correct, I only typed it as an `IClass` because I did not know how to specify that I want the argument to be an implementation of `IClass`. I actually have several implementations of `IClass`, but inside of `useIt` (of course this is not the real name) I am creating an instance of the implementation, but want usage of that to be limited to the `IClass` interface.

In the real code, I am actually creating some dependent structures, then calling the `MyClass` constructor (again, simplified name) with them, thus the need for passing in the class, itself.

Comment: This could be done in another way, of course, but I wanted to know how this specific use case would be defined in Flow.

Comment: Where does `IStore` magically come from?

Comment: Sorry, IStore was the original. I modified this to simplify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a `Class<.>` wrapper on the argument's type (`useIt(TheClass: IClass)` should be `useIt(TheClass: Class<IClass>)`). That, and interfaces don't assume a default constructor, so you'll need an explicit one on IClass (with return type `void`).

Comment: [Confirmed that it works](https://flow.org/try/#0JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIGEA2cDOPkDeAUMsggPYg5hQCuCY5UAFAJQBcyAbucACYBuEskjVmcKAHNOAZRqhJHZAAUo5ALbAcEADwAqAHxEAvkSIJseZAFkAnllz5g6gA6YI6iOHwZL+YqS4tiAIIhBiEoqEyHAA7nDAYMh85DgaEGAAFgriUqzIpqZEQSHIMLQhYMCUyLTaqGDMACqZEA54nO04Or6OBvkBZJTUyOQARgBWyAC8yCAQscgtbX5swuMTAHSijQDkkbusJkA). Certainly better than what I suggested in the comment (now deleted (it was `$Subtype<...>`)) because flow finds the `string` <-> `String` mismatch.

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I was looking for!  I did try `Class` at one point, but the Generic argument was key.